# Upload photo with Graph API - redirect back to site afterwards?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have working code that will upload photo from form. However when I do submit form it redirects me to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=mytokencode` and content is

```
{
   "id": "116980435091338"
}
```

The question is: How can I redirect from this back to my site? Is it even possible? Maybe I should pass some additional parameter like, for example `?redirect_to=http://site.com/`.

And also is it possible to get photo ID back to PHP somehow so I can get photo URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit your form to the server and have the server do the HTTP POST command instead. See this example from Facebook:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: Yes, I have a working example of this, but it uploads the file to server first. I want to upload it straight to FB

Comment: Then you wont have control over where the browser goes to next.  If you send it to your webserver, then you can response.redirect the user to anywhere you want or even serve down different html after the post happens.

Comment: Then you will need to use AJAX to upload the file asynchronously, parse the response and then redirect the user. Although, I still prefer doing it at server side.

Comment: You also can do a normal form post to your server (rather a form post directly to the Graph) as an alternative to AJAX.